# Going through latitude and longitude of a country

Tags: python, api, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have an interesting project.

So I have a WEB API that receives two parameters, longitude and latitude and that responds true or false being true that there is some resources in an circle with center (lat,long) and radio X (let say 10 miles).

If it responds true I have to call it again until it responds False.

If it responds false I don't have to call it again

When I get false I have to change (lat,long) so I search for those resources in other area different than the previous one until I cover all the territory of a country.
I want to automatize it with python to cover for example all the USA territory. How can I do it?

I was thinking of starting from San Diego (bottom-left of USA) and going all the way up to Seattle or something like that. But, how can I know the delimiters (latitude and longitude) of the USA territory.

I don't know if I did explain correctly what I want to do. If not, please just tell me and I'll try better.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the vincenty distance function available on `geopy` third party module. You have to install geopy from `pypi` using `pip install geopy`.

Here is the an example of how you would then write your code:

```
from geopy.distance import vincenty
this_country = (latitude, longitude)
radius = 10  # 10 miles

while radius >= 0:
    other_country_within_circle_found = False
    # other_countries is a list of tuples which are lat & long
    # positions of other country eg. (-12.3456, 78.91011)
    for other_country in other_countries:
        # note: other_country = (latitude, longitude)
        if other_country == this_country:
            continue  # skip if other country is the same as this country.
        distance = vincenty(this_country, other_country).miles
        if distance <= radius:
            other_country_within_circle_found = True
            break
    if not other_country_within_circle_found:
        # the circle of this radius, have no other countries inside it.
        break
    radius -= 1  # reduce the circle radius by 1 mile.
```

Refer to geopy documentation for more info: https://geopy.readthedocs.org/en/1.10.0/#module-geopy.distance